# PostgreSQL disable all database constraints

Tags: postgresql

I need to import the data into my PostgreSQL database but existing import script doing the job in a wrong order and fails with constraint violation error.

Is it possible in PostgreSQL to disable all constraints check before import and enable back it when needed ? If so, could you please show an example or commands how it can be achieved ?

Comment: You probably want `deferred` constraints. (read "temporaly disabled, but checked at commit time")

Comment: Could you please provide a mode detailed answer how it can help to solve my problem ?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-set-constraints.html (but it is probably a good idea to also fix the order of events in your scriptt)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to this import tool, this is a black box tool to me.

Comment: And also, I can't catch the transactions for this tool in order to execute SET CONSTRAINTS DEFERRED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should raise this issue with the import tool producers.

There is no simple way to temporarily disable constraints; you'd have to drop and recreate them yourself. Looking at the output `pg_dump --section=post-data` should help, as it contains commands to create all constraints towards the end.